# Looking for paper ‘Lyndon bases and the multiplicative formula for R-matrices’ by M.Rosso

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, paper-request

Does anyone have a link to the paper ‘Lyndon bases and the multiplicative formula for R-matrices’ by M. Rosso? I cannot find it in Google Scholar or Z-Lib. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be an unpublished preprint. Why don't you ask the [author](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~marc.rosso/)?

Comment: @abx Thank you for your information!